# Pandas Combine Columns While Keeping Value Relationships

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame([["NaN", "HIGH", "MID", "156", "12"], ["MID", "NaN", "LOW", "151", "12"], ["TOP", "NaN", "MID", "150", "12"]], columns=["1", "2", "3", "id", "group"])

     1     2    3   id group
0  NaN  HIGH  MID  156    12
1  MID   NaN  LOW  151    12
2  TOP   NaN  MID  150    12
```

That I want to merge with a larger dataset with multiple groups that's formatted like this

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["1", "NaN", "156", "12"], ["1", "MID", "151", "12"], ["1", "TOP", "150", "12"], ["2", "HIGH", "156", "12"], ["2", "NaN", "151", "12"], ["2", "NaN", "150", "12"], ["3", "MID", "156", "12"], ["3", "LOW", "151", "12"], ["3", "MID", "150", "12"]], columns=["trial", "level", "id", "group"])
  

    trial level id group
0     1   NaN  156    12
1     1   MID  151    12
2     1   TOP  150    12
3     2  HIGH  156    12
4     2   NaN  151    12
5     2   NaN  150    12
6     3   MID  156    12
7     3   LOW  151    12
8     3   MID  150    12
```

How can I combine the [1, 2, 3] columns from the first df into df2's single trial column while maintaining the corresponding relationship between each id's level in each trial?

The actual df2 doesn't include the NaN values I just put them to see the format clearly, so I'd like to also not include the rows where the id doesn't have a level (NaN) in that trial.

Comment: `df1.melt(['id', 'group'], var_name='trial', value_name='level')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `melt`

```
out = df.melt(['id','group'])
Out[245]: 
    id group variable value
0  156    12        1   NaN
1  151    12        1   MID
2  150    12        1   TOP
3  156    12        2  HIGH
4  151    12        2   NaN
5  150    12        2   NaN
6  156    12        3   MID
7  151    12        3   LOW
8  150    12        3   MID
```